# Retrieve all flux elements in StepVerifier

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am working on testing a flux. I don't know how many elements exactly the flux has. Initially I have tried with StepVerifier and faced issues as i do not know the elements. Later I have referred this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762798/how-to-perform-assertion-on-all-remaining-elements-in-stepverifier) and tried the same but I am getting the below error:
`java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onNext`

My understanding is that, my code is expecting a complete signal but the flux has some more elements left(so it gives onNext() instead of onComplete()). Please help me to understand where I am missing things. Below is my code:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux)
            .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
            .consumeRecordedWith(elements-> {assertThat(elements.size()).isGreaterThan(0);})
            .verifyComplete();
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're not actually consuming your Flux, you're just setting up what happens *when it's consumed*. Your `verifyComplete();` call then fails, understandably, because the Flux hasn't been consumed at all, and it's thus not complete!

**You need to add a `thenConsumeWhile()` call to actually consume it.**

If you *really* need to use `AssertJ` as you do above, then you can do:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux)
        .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
        .thenConsumeWhile(x -> true)
        .consumeRecordedWith(elements -> {
            assertThat(elements.isEmpty()).isFalse();
        })
        .verifyComplete();
```

However, there's no need for `AssertJ` here - the reactor test package is enough, and adding additional testing frameworks makes the testing code much less clear IMHO. So if you're not wedded to AssertJ, just do:

```
StepVerifier.create(flux)
        .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
        .thenConsumeWhile(x -> true)
        .expectRecordedMatches(elements -> !elements.isEmpty())
        .verifyComplete();
```

Note that in real-world use, you'd probably want to adjust the predicate in `thenConsumeWhile` so that it runs a check against each element in turn, too. I've also adjusted the above code to use `isEmpty()` rather than checking if `size()>0`, as it's semantically clearer while achieving the same purpose.

Comment: it's a great answer. How can I ensure the StepVerifier will end in a certain time? If there is a bug  in my program, the flux may never complete. It means it will run for a very long time in, says, a CI server.

Comment: `.expectComplete().verify(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))` or `StepVerifier.setDefaultTimeout()` can help in that case @AnthonyKong

Comment: In practice, I have also found that this answer obscures any errors that come down the flux which can make finding out why a test failed hard. I haven't found a way around this.

Comment: Hi @Michael Berry, just came across this answer with the same problem more or less. I was curious with you saying that "we shouldnt need AssertJ" with reactor. In my scenario, in some steps of my pipeline I do an HTTP call to 3rd party services and I would like to test if those calls were done correctly. The way I'm doing it is `Capturing` the parameters and then using assertion to test. Do you see any other way of doing it? 

Comment: @JoãoMenighin Horrendously late reply - but I meant there's no need for `AssertJ` in the use case presented in the question. More in-depth requirements like the one you outlined will still require it, and that's all good

Answer (score 2):

From the same issue, with something new: **I had so many entries in my flux that it couldn't fit into the memory** *(yes, those test case fixtures were designed that way)*...

So buffering everything into a `List` wasn't an option.

And I tried different API methods on `StepVerifier` and found the following to work:

```java
StepVerifier.create( myFlux )
  .thenConsumeWhile( Predicate<T>, Consumer<T> )
  .verifyComplete();
```

I literally did

```java
StepVerifier.create( myFlux )
  .thenConsumeWhile( __ -> true, entry -> {
    // assertions
  } )
  .verifyComplete();
```

Comment: I did save the consumer by returning false after asserting in the predicate, FYI