# How does StepVerifier's "recording" feature work?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Why does this test fail?

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StepVerifierTest {
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = List.of(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin")
        );
        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(roles).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast))
                .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
                .expectRecordedMatches(actualRoles -> actualRoles.containsAll(roles))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectRecordedMatches" failed (expected collection predicate match; actual: [user])
```

For some reason, `StepVerifier` put only the first element in the collection and then rushed to check the predicate. The documentation says

> Start a recording session storing Subscriber.onNext(Object) **values** in the supplied Collection.

My expectation was that `StepVerifier` would poll elements till the stream is exhausted and only then check the predicate

`StepVerifier`'s API doesn't suggest I should manually "record" emitted elements

Note please that this question is **not** about "how do I make the test pass". I know how

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = List.of(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin")
        );
        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(roles).collectList())
                .expectNextMatches(actualRoles -> actualRoles.containsAll(roles))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();

/*
This, on the other hand, won't do since it asserts not only 
on the content but also on the order of elements

        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(roles))
                .expectNextSequence(roles)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
*/
    }
```

Instead, I'm curious how that "recording" feature works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a count expectation between `recordWith()` and `expectRecordedMatches()`. I figure it trggers those `onNext()` calls

```java
    @Test
    void test() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = List.of(
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user"),
                new SimpleGrantedAuthority("admin")
        );
        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(roles).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast))
                .recordWith(ArrayList::new)
                .expectNextCount(2)
                .expectRecordedMatches(actualRoles -> actualRoles.containsAll(roles))
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
    }
```

[Simone Basle's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44764644/23299948), I reckon, would be to do something like this (the guy's [former lead](https://fr.linkedin.com/in/simonbasle/en) at Project Reactor):

```java
        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(roles).map(GrantedAuthority.class::cast))
                .thenConsumeWhile(roles::contains)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
```

However, it passes even if the `Flux` omits elements

```java
        StepVerifier.create(Flux.fromIterable(roles).take(1))
                .thenConsumeWhile(roles::contains)
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
```